# What is Puppet's equivalent of input validation using stdlib in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

**Problem**

The following [issue](https://github.com/030/ansible-sensu-client/issues/83) appears in the ansible-sensu-client:

```
{"timestamp":"2017-01-19T09:49:14.803754+0000","level":"fatal","message":
"check name cannot contain spaces or special characters","object":{"handlers":
["mailer","sms"],"command":"check-ports.rb  -p 234","interval":30,"standalone":
true,"name":"port 234"}}
```

At the moment the user needs to debug the sensu-client logging in order to find the issue, will the issue could be prevented by validating the input.

**Aim**

To avoid that users that use this role will use names that contain spaces or special characters, e.g.:

```
sensu_client_checks_metrics_common:
  - cmd: check-cpu
  - cmd: check-memory-percent
  - cmd: check-ntp
  - cmd: check-swap-percent
    handlers:
      - mailer
  - cmd: metrics-cpu
    handlers: 
      - relay
  - cmd: metrics-memory-percent
    handlers: 
      - relay
  - cmd: metrics-disk
    handlers: 
      - relay
  - cmd: metrics-disk-usage
    handlers: 
      - relay
```

by letting the Ansible run fail and indicate that the input is invalid

**Discussion**

In Puppet one could use [Stdlib](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/stdlib/3.2.1) to validate input, e.g. is variable X a String and does Y equals Hash? For example, in [this module](https://github.com/030/puppet-git/blob/master/manifests/params.pp#L5) the version should be a string and if that is not the case the Puppet run will fail:

```
validate_string($version)
```

and indicate that version needs to be a string.

How to validate input in Ansible as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [assert](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/assert_module.html) module in the beginning of your roles to validate variable values:

```
- assert:
    that:
      - "my_param <= 100"
      - "my_param >= 0"
    msg: "'my_param' must be between 0 and 100"
```

Comment: And what could be done if strings need to be checked that reside in a variable that is a hash?

Comment: @030 give an exampe, please

Comment: added the `sensu_client_checks_metrics_common` example

Comment: not sure what you want to check here, but you can use `parent.child.string_to_check` like with any other variables